# Send more than one raw transaction quickly will throw an error

Tags: transactions, sendrawtransaction

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(function(v){
    count = v;
    var amount = web3.utils.toHex(1e16);
    var rawTransaction = {"from":addressFrom, "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(20* 1e9),"gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(210000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0","data":contract.methods.transfer(addressTo, amount).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)}
    var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction);
    transaction.sign(privKey);
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
    .on('transactionHash',console.log);
});
```

If I send more than one raw transaction quickly, I get the known transaction error. I got

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: known transaction: 288cd7f1dc2dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

Maybe something is without the 0x, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this is because when you send two raw transactions quickly, both of your transactions get the same nonce value as you are passing the transaction count of the address as nonce. So in quick sending, transaction count doesn't get updated. Hope it helps!